# Random identifier vs identifier plus HMAC

Tags: authentication, hash, random

Suppose I have a resource that I want to be accessible only using a specific link. I could generate a link using a 256 bit random identifier, e.g. `https://example.com/aMXtSQufIxntoMSnTQGdgMfs84VzM-ae7gog1hoqojS`—then only the user in possession of the link could access the resource. Malicious users would be unable to access the link because it is infeasible to correctly guess a valid ID in such a large space.

Instead of doing this, I could instead use a 128 bit random identifier, followed by a 128 bit HMAC of that ID generated using a key that is known only to the server (let's ignore for now whether or not we can have a 128 bit HMAC).

A good HMAC creates a uniformly distributed output, so in both cases we would effectively have a 256 bit random number.

Is the HMAC version more secure? Could you explain?

Comment: HMAC primary use is for performing authentication on some data. From what you mention, you use it simply for its "random" output, so in this case why not just sticking to the output of your PRNG generator?

Comment: I guess my idea was that it made it a "verified" link, but I had a hunch that it didn't necessarily improve the security and couldn't really articulate why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go with the 256-bit random identifier**

Based on your (ideal) assumptions, both should have the same level of security. However, I believe that technically the **HMAC solution could introduce weaknesses** simply because its value is derived from the value of the first 128-bit part. Although using proper implementation of cryptographic functions should prevent anyone to generate valid links, real world mishaps (key exposure) or progress in cryptanalysis could make it happen.

In case of a link compromise, the first method easily allows you to generate a new link. Your HMAC-based solution will force you to generate a new 128 random part and its HMAC, exposing your links to possible [known-plaintext attacks.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) Key exposire would require you to change your key and regenerate all your links. Add to that the key management, proper cryptographic implementation, etc.

More complexity doesn't imply more security.

Comment: I understand the second option to be an HMAC of the first value with the server key, not a HMAC of the contents of the file.

Comment: You are right and I corrected my post, thanks. It doesn't change my reasoning and conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Since only the server knows the key to the HMAC it's the only one who can verify the authenticity of a link.

This could be used to differentiate between a random guess and a once valid link.  An IP could be harshly penalized for successive invalid guesses which fail this check.  It could also be used to short circuit going and looking for a record.  Not sure if a single HMAC is faster than the lookup.

As for the total randomness, while a HMAC's output is a fairly random distribution, it is deterministic given an input and key.  So every number in the first 128-bits maps to a single 256-bit output.  Though in it's totality it appears random to the casual observer, there are only 2^128 values.  Whereas in a totally random scheme the first 128-bits are independent of the last 128-bits.